# How to check if ONLY a combination of values exist in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a list of values and i want to get only the rows where the column has ONLY a combination of values:

```
Ex:
>CREATE TABLE User_Group(
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [names] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

    Sample content User_Group:
    1:" Joe,Jane"
    2:"Jane, James,Frank"
    3: "Jane, Joe,James"
```

I am being passed in a list of names and I want to check if the combination of names exist in the User_group table and return the rows. I want the rows ONLY if it contains the EXACT combination.

So for example, if i am given James,Jane and Joe, i want to check 2^3-1 times if James,Jane, Joe,James&Jane,James&Joe, Jane&joe, James&Jane&Joe exist in the table. And from this scenario i should only get rows 1 and 3. Row 2 is skipped because it has Frank.

I know i can do exist but not sure how to check for only that particular combination.

I am also not sure how to "loop" through all the combinations - i thought about using Java to make 2^x-1 calls with different combinations (given the scenario it is highly unlikely the combination will be >15).

I also read about "Select All" but not sure if that helps with only distinct combination either.

How can i elegantly achieve this?

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store lists in strings!  Have a junction/association table with one row per member in the group.

Comment: How will that resolve a combination of members?

Comment: why `row 1` is the expected result when it does not contain `James` ?

Comment: because it has a combination of subset of the 3 given

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that uses CTEs to do what you want.

I create a table @list that contains the lists you gave, and anoter table @search that contain each of the search terms.

```
declare @list table(k int, l varchar(100))
insert @list values (1,' Joe,Jane')
,(2,'Jane, James,Frank')
,(3,'Jane, Joe,James')

declare @search table(sk int,s varchar(20))
insert @search values (1,'jane'),(2,'joe'),(3,'james')

-- Top level CTE to remove spaces, and each term is surrounded by its own commas.
;with cte as (
    select k,','+replace(replace(l,',',',,'),' ','')+',' l from @list
    )
-- Go through the search terms recursively and remove the search terms, with their surrounding commas
,cte2 as(
    select cte.k, replace(cte.l,','+s+',','') as l, s.sk, s.s 
    from cte
    join @search s on sk=1
    union all
    select cte2.k, replace(cte2.l,','+s.s+',','') as l, s.sk ,s.s
    from cte2
    join @search s on s.sk=cte2.sk+1
)
-- Find any that result in zero length
select distinct k from cte2 where len(l)=0
```

Comment: CTE is kind of new concept to me but i read and got the general gist of the concept. 
From CTE are you adding extra "," to the string?
So 'Jane, James,Frank' becomes 'Jane,,James,,Frank'?

for CTE2 why do you have join @search s on sk=1?

And if i am passing the search values to the SQL (e.g. java sql call) instead of having the parameters in a table like List, is the SQL a bit different since i will need to explicitly include them? will this work with any combination and subset of the 3 names given?

Comment: With the commas, I wanted to make sure you got the complete name. So testing for "Jo" followed by "Anne" would not also strip out "Joanne". With the CTE the first part of the union is known as the anchor, which you can think of as the starting point. If you are passing the lists in, then inserting the string into a temporary table or table variable should be easy enough, and means the rest can be done in pure sql.

Comment: Ok, I tested and it works! Still trying to wrap my head around how it recursively checked for subsets lol...   by the way, is there a way to deal with names with spaces in between? I ended up putting a _  in place of space for now. It's not a huge deal but if using first and last name together the space will cause issues.

Comment: Well you could come up with a way, but I noticed in your sample that some of the lists had spaces in the list, some did not. You could just replace comma followed by a space with comma instead of stripping all spaces, but that still leaves you open to multiple spaces. Best idea would be to clean up your data!

Comment: Yeah i tried to make them random. But the names will be full names like "Frank doe" or something. I know the way it is now it works with "Frank_doe" and most likely "Frank_jane_doe" since theres no space. But the way you have it you  stripped the spaces so it matches the value exactly right?

I dont think it is too bad if i do a simple replace space with _ for now because there could be multiple spaces per entry.